# How to match a multi-tag substring?

Tags: php, html, substring, preg-match

I can't seems to get my expected result (should be "found") using the codes below, can someone correct my code? I keep getting this following error:

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '<' in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\lio\lio2.php on line 24
>   not found

```
$content= file_get_contents('http://exampleonly.com');
$html ='
<a id="statusSectionTESTAUTOMATION" class="statusIcon">
<span title="Last build failed" class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-error"><span>The last build was not built</span>
</span>
</a>';

if(preg_match_all($content, $html))
{
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

---

I also tried using this example, since the `$content` on the above codes was just a dummy. I try to apply it with a live url, and instead of using `preg_match_all()` I used `stristr()`.

```
$content= file_get_contents('http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/');
$html =
'
<td style="height:50px;border-bottom:1px solid #D8DFEA;" valign="top"><div class="ts1"></div>
<a href="http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/netflix.com.html" style="font-weight:700;">
Netflix</a>
<div class="status" style="margin-top:3px;">
<span class="up"></span>Netflix.com is up. Checked 0 seconds ago.</div>
</td>
';
if(stristr($content, $html))
{
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? And what is the output of $content?
Please give a proper example

Comment: hi sorry about the example, here I try a different example, and using stristr instead of preg_match_all  | $content= file_get_contents('http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/');
$html =
'
<td style="height:50px;border-bottom:1px solid #D8DFEA;" valign="top"><div class="ts1"></div>
<a href="http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/netflix.com.html" style="font-weight:700;">
Netflix</a>
<div class="status" style="margin-top:3px;">
<span class="up"></span>Netflix.com is up. Checked 0 seconds ago.</div>
</td>
';
if(stristr($content, $html))
{
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all` is used to check for existence of pattern.
use `stristr` for searching substring within the string.

```
$content= file_get_contents('http://exampleonly.com');
$html ='
<a id="statusSectionTESTAUTOMATION" class="statusIcon">
<span title="Last build failed" class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-error"><span>The last build was not built</span>
</span>
</a>';

if(stristr($content, $html))
{
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Comment: hi tried it using the example below (using a live url) but still getting "not found"  $content= file_get_contents('http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/');
$html =
'
<td style="height:50px;border-bottom:1px solid #D8DFEA;" valign="top"><div class="ts1"></div>
<a href="http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/netflix.com.html" style="font-weight:700;">
Netflix</a>
<div class="status" style="margin-top:3px;">
<span class="up"></span>Netflix.com is up. Checked 0 seconds ago.</div>
</td>
';
if(stristr($content, $html))
{
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}

Comment: @Liyo Html content is changing for this site. I think you are concerned about whether netflix is `up` or not. If you are, then just check for `Netflix.com is up.`

Comment: yep actually I "isitdownrightnow.com" is similar to my actual website(internal site) which I have to check the similar icon status which is changing too. (example of status: "complete" and "ongoing", which in isitidownrightnow.com is "down" and "up" ) I was wondering if I can check it by basing the html tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try [**strpos**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.

example use :

```
$content= file_get_contents('http://exampleonly.com');
$html ='
    <a id="statusSectionTESTAUTOMATION" class="statusIcon">
<span title="Last build failed" class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-error"><span>The last build was not built</span>
</span>
</a>';

if (strpos($html, $content) !== false) {
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found"; 
}
```

**Important** : use of `!==` is deliberate and NOT `!=`

Comment: also tried strpos, using the a live url as example. but still getting "not found" for your ref. $content= file_get_contents('http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/');
$html =
'
<td style="height:50px;border-bottom:1px solid #D8DFEA;" valign="top"><div class="ts1"></div>
<a href="http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/netflix.com.html" style="font-weight:700;">
Netflix</a>
<div class="status" style="margin-top:3px;">
<span class="up"></span>Netflix.com is up. Checked 0 seconds ago.</div>
</td>
';
if (strpos($html, $content) !== false) {
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found"; 
}

Comment: yup sorry, it seems that when i pasted the code it automatically converted to a link, but yeah on my code I has http://, kindly check the screenshot. but it seems that it still not working, i only get "not found" as the result [IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/s6owgm.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see this seemingly abandoned question find a resolution, offer a bit of education, and urge some best practices.

First, *why are you getting an error on your `preg_match_all()` attempt?* It is because the function is expecting the first parameter to be a regex pattern and you are offering a literal string.  To fix this error you only need to place [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) on both sides of `$html`'s value.  In this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hUChUu/1), you will see that I use `~` instead of the more popular `/` because this avoids having to "escape" the `/` in the pattern itself.

```
$html='~
<a id="statusSectionTESTAUTOMATION" class="statusIcon">
<span title="Last build failed" class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-error"><span>The last build was not built</span>
</span>
</a>~'
```

As a matter of efficiency and best practice, I should state that if you are only checking if the substring exists, then using `preg_match_all()` -- which searches for multiple occurrences -- is overkill.  If using a preg_match function for your case, use `preg_match()`.

Furthermore, I would like to strongly urge you to cut down your search text.  It is an atypically large number of characters to be searching for.

If you don't need the newline character(s) at the start of your search text, remove them.  If there is a newline (invisible white-space character(s)) at the start or end of `$html` but not in `$content` you will not get a match. It is also entirely possible that there is a clash between on `\r\n` and `\n` not matching between your `$content` and `$html` or because you hit <kbd>return</kbd> after your `'` at the start of `$html` and <kbd>return</kbd> before your final `'` causing the mismatch.

The deeper question is, can you search for `id="statusSectionTESTAUTOMATION"` or `title="Last build failed"` or `aui-iconfont-error` while maintaining accuracy?

If not, is this enough? `id="statusSectionTESTAUTOMATION" class="statusIcon">
<span title="Last build failed" class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-error"` ?

If your search text is literal and static, you will be better advised to use a non-regex solution.  You seem to be searching for a very distinct substring, so I don't know if case-sensitivity is an issue -- you will have to decide on that matter.

`stristr()` **is bad advice from Sahil** (and he has given this advice else where on SO) because it "over-performs" for your usage and is less efficient than `stripos()`.  These non-regex functions will literally check for your substring (and of course don't require the delimiters previously mentioned).

**Dr Manish Joshi's code snippet is incorrect** because it has reversed the "haystack" and the "needle" (which is an easy mistake to make).  For a case-sensitive search, you can accurately use something like this: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3045c558aad3baac9cfb4eb46b55dd8dbfee3444))

```
$content='some text
    <a id="statusSectionTESTAUTOMATION" class="statusIcon">
<span title="Last build failed" class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-error"><span>The last build was not built</span>
</span>
</a>some text';
$html ='<span title="Last build failed" class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-error"><span>The last build was not built</span>';

if(strpos($content,$html)!==false){
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found"; 
}
// output: found
```